# Add byte to array removes capitalized letters

Tags: c#, hex

I try to add a byte to an array as shown below:

```
messagedata.Add((byte)0xF0);
```

But then when I check the array, the item looks like 0xf0 but it since it's going to be a MIDI message I found it has to be a capital F. What can I do to keep the letters capitalized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to keep the letter capitalized, because the letters aren't stored in the array. The only thing stored in the array is a numerical value, and `0xf0` is just one of the way to represent that value as text.

You don't need to keep the letter capitalized. A MIDI message is sent as bytes, not text, so `0xf0` and `0xF0` are textual representations of the same value. There are other ways to represent the same value as text, as `240`, `0360` or `%11110000`, and they all mean the same thing.

This code:

```
messagedata.Add((byte)240);
```

produces the exact same result as your code above. The executable code will be identical, and it's not possible to determine which code was used by examining the compiled code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Seems the problem lies in something else: when an integer (for example 1) is converted, it results in 0x00 but I need 0x31... any advice?

Comment: @internetmw: If you convert the integer value `1` into a byte, you will get a byte with the value `1`, or `0x01`. Pehaps you want to convert the character value `'1'` into a byte, which gives the value `49` or `0x31`.

Answer (score 0):

0xF0 and 0xf0 are the same thing. When you look and see 0xf0 (with a debugger or whatever) that tool simply decided to use lower case letters. F and f both mean 4 bits all equal to 1